# storing c++ linked lists pointers in a vector

Tags: c++

I want to create a number of lists and store a pointer to each of the lists in a vector.
That i achieved but my problem is accessing the list in certain functions.
I have a function that checks the order in which the nodes are linked and invalidates certain lists based on their order.  The function bool isValid() does the invalidation.

```
bool Train::isValid() const
{
    Car* curr;
    Car* temp;
    Car* Fin;
    Car* MVP;
    bool result;
    curr = m_head->getNext();
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        temp = curr->getNext();
        Fin = temp->getNext();
        MVP = Fin->getNext();
        if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==2)||(curr->getCargo()==2)&&(temp->getCargo()==3))
            result = false;
        else if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==3)&&(Fin->getCargo()==3))
            result = false;
        else if((curr->getCargo()==0)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==0)&&(MVP->getCargo()==0)&&((Fin->getNext())->getCargo()==0))
            result = false;
        else if((curr->getCargo()==4)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==4))
            result = false;
        else
            result = true;
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code section below is where I am accessing the vector elements.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<Vec.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<": "<<*Vec.at(i)<<endl;
    }
    typ = Vec.at((A/1111)-1)->Stringconverter(REMOVE);
    Vec.at((A/1111)-1)->removeCar((CARGO_TYPE)typ);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i<Vec.size();i++)
    {
        bool N = Vec.at(i)->isValid();
            if(N)
        cout<<i+1<<": "<<*Vec.at(i)<<"(valid)"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<i+1<<": "<<*Vec.at(i)<<"(invalid)"<<endl;
    }
```

The part where I am caliing the function isValid()

Comment: Code is calling `temp = curr->getNext(); Fin = temp->getNext(); MVP = Fin->getNext();`, I am not sure about code structure, but if `curr` is last element, then there will be problem when possessing next element. In the next line there is call on this not existing element `Fin->getNext();`. It doesn't look good.

Comment: And your question is? And is `Vec.at((A/1111)-1)` by intend? For all `A<1111` an exception will be thrown.

Comment: curr is not the last pointer. It points to the next node after head node. I tried debugging the code and execution breaks at the function call

Comment: Do I need to have additional while loops to check if the pointers point to null too?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a bug in your code:

```
while(curr != NULL)   // NULL!! (the language supports nullptr)
{
    temp = curr->getNext();

    // Do not check `temp` is not nullptr before calling getNext()
    Fin = temp->getNext();

    // Do not check `Fin` is not nullptr before calling getNext()
    MVP = Fin->getNext();

    // Again in all the following (you don't check temp of Fin is not nullptr.
    if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==2)||(curr->getCargo()==2)&&(temp->getCargo()==3))
        result = false;
    else if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==3)&&(Fin->getCargo()==3))
        result = false;
    else if((curr->getCargo()==0)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==0)&&(MVP->getCargo()==0)&&((Fin->getNext())->getCargo()==0))
        result = false;
    else if((curr->getCargo()==4)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==4))
        result = false;
    else
        result = true;
    curr = curr->getNext();
}

// The result is just the value from the last iteration of the above
// loop. The last iteration of the above loop curr is valid but
// curr->getNext() returns nullptr so temp is nullptr.
// Thus the call temp->getNext() has undefined value.
// So the value of result is completely unknowable.
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insights, really helped.
This is the new functional code

```
bool Train::isValid() const
{
    Car* curr;
    Car* temp;
    Car* Fin;
    Car* MVP;
    bool result;

    //Setting current node to the head node's next, head node will always be a locomotive, hence not involved.
    curr = m_head->getNext();

    //If any of the condition returns false, the loop should break.
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        temp = curr->getNext();       //Setting first trail node to the current node's next
        if(temp != NULL)
        {
        Fin = temp->getNext();             //Setting second trail node to the first trail node's next

        //Condition for combustible car being next to a oxidizer car
        if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==2)||(curr->getCargo()==2)&&(temp->getCargo()==3))           
        {
            result = false;break;
        }
        else
            result = true;
        if(Fin != NULL)
        {
        MVP = Fin->getNext();              //Setting third trail node to the second trail node's next

        //Condition for three combustible cars being in a row
        if((curr->getCargo()==3)&&(temp->getCargo()==3)&&(Fin->getCargo()==3))
        {
                result = false;break;
        }

        //Condition for a radioactive car being next to a biological car
        else if((curr->getCargo()==4)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==4))
        {
                result = false;break;
        }
        else
            result = true;
        if(MVP != NULL)
        {

            //Condition for five biological cars being in a row
        if((curr->getCargo()==0)&&(temp->getCargo()==0)&&(Fin->getCargo()==0)&&(MVP->getCargo()==0)&&((Fin->getNext())->getCargo()==0))
        {
                result = false;break;
        }
        else
            result = true;
        }
        }
        }

        //moving current node to its next
        curr = curr->getNext();
    }
    return result;
}
```